# how to have core login and overridden login at a same time?

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides

I overridden login controller and placed it in my local directory. I have seperate login.phtml as well. It is working fine. But I would like to have core/Mage/ login as well.

Below is my Mage\Customer\Controllers\AccountController.php

```
<?php

class Mage_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    /**
     * Customer login form page
     */
    public function loginAction()
    {
        echo 'Mage'; die;
        if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Login-Required', 'true');
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

Below is my local directory account controller

```
<?php
require_once 'Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php';
class Ucs_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{

.
.
.

    /**
     * Customer login form page
     */
    public function popuploginAction()
    {
        if ($this->_getSession()->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Login-Required', 'true');
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

When I access my overridden loginAction it automatically redirects to core login method.

I am trying to access overridden popuplogin as below

http://localhost/magento/index.php/customer/account/popuplogin/

and core login as below

http://localhost/magento/index.php/customer/account/login/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the `Mage_Customer_AccountController` class, you will see it implements the `preDispatch` function.

That function checks if you are trying to access an action from the controller that doesn't require the user to be logged in. And the allowed actions are the ones in the `$openActions` array.
If the user is not allowed, Magento runs the following code, which redirects a non-logged in user to the default login action of Magento.

```
$this->_getSession()->authenticate($this)
```

Since that method doesn't load the actions from some variable or anything else, there are two ways to achieve what you need:

1. Create a new route for your module, without rewriting the `/customer` route. And your controller would extend the `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action` class instead of the `Mage_Customer_AccountController` class.
   Example: `http://localhost/magento/index.php/ucs/customer/popuplogin`
   You can still make your custom form post to `customer/account/loginPost`.
2. Re-implement the preDispatch method in your class, and add your own action as an allowed one.
   Though, since you do not need the `preDispatch` of `Mage_Customer_AccountController`, but you still need its parent's `preDispatch`, replace `parent::preDispatch();` with `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::preDsipatch()`.

This is how the function would look like, if you chose the second method:

```
public function preDispatch()
{
    // a brute-force protection here would be nice

    Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action::preDispatch();

    if (!$this->getRequest()->isDispatched()) {
        return;
    }

    $action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();
    $openActions = array(
        'create',
        'login',
        'logoutsuccess',
        'forgotpassword',
        'forgotpasswordpost',
        'resetpassword',
        'resetpasswordpost',
        'confirm',
        'confirmation',
        'popuplogin',
    );
    $pattern = '/^(' . implode('|', $openActions) . ')/i';

    if (!preg_match($pattern, $action)) {
        if (!$this->_getSession()->authenticate($this)) {
            $this->setFlag('', 'no-dispatch', true);
        }
    } else {
        $this->_getSession()->setNoReferer(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just like to add, that my personal preference is the first option.

Comment: I choose second option and when I try with this, popuplogin template render properly, but Core mage login not renders the login page.

Comment: @version_0.1 Do you still have that `die;` in the `loginAction` function? Did you change the login page's layout? If the login page was rendering correctly before implementing the `preDispatch` function, I see no reason how this might affect it. What gets rendered when you open the login page?

Comment: I remove the die. Now popuplogin page renders perfectly, but when I open login only header and footer appears not the main area.

Comment: Did you do any modification to the <customer_account_login> update handle in any of your layout xml files?

Comment: I havent make any changes but still I'm getting the error.. This is not impact of popuplogin, when I disabled that module that time also same, since I am using svn I checked for file modification on any layout, but no idea :-(